# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version - delete query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I can't tell what is wrong here, i have tried replacing WHERE Id = '$id' and still not working. removing WHERE CLAUSE makes it works fine. Id variable does not have any problem it has it's value. can someone help me figure this out? thanks

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  $status = $con->exec("UPDATE wine SET ConfirmStatus = 'confirmed' WHERE Id = '".$id."' ");
```

Comment: Use parameters in the query.  When you munge query strings by dumping user input into them, you run the risk of introducing syntax errors.  Why bother?

Comment: is `Id` a numeric type?

Comment: i tried gettype($id) and it shows that id is string type

Comment: I mean in table `wine`...

Comment: Id from DB is int type

Comment: Let's see the query _after_ it is built:  `$sql = "..."; echo $sql;`, then `...exec($sql);`  After that, check for errors and display the error message.

Comment: Eh?  Title says "delete", code says "UPDATE"??

Comment: oops sorry, my mistake. its actually update. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without enclosing the `$id`- value within `' '`:

```
  $status = $con->exec("UPDATE wine SET ConfirmStatus = 'confirmed' WHERE Id = ".$id);
```

If it then works, please still consider Gordon's comment regarding using parameters...

Comment: thanks man! i removed the single quote and change it to Id = ".$id." :)